# Optimizing a buffering sample for parallel execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this buffering algorithm

```
while (aufnahme || ArrayAnsammlung.Count > 1)
{
    if (ArrayAnsammlung != null)
    {
        int l = ArrayAnsammlung.Count - 1;
        //db(l.ToString());


        for (int DurchLaeufer = 0; DurchLaeufer < l; DurchLaeufer++)
        {
            if (ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer] != null)
            {
                Nummerierung = Convert.ToString(Nummerierungszaehler);
                Enkodierung = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                Enkodierung.FlipHorizontal = true;
                //Enkodierung.FlipVertical = false;
                var dateiStrom = new FileStream("E:\\Temp\\" + datum + " " + Nummerierung.PadLeft(12, '0') + ".jpg", FileMode.Create);
                Enkodierung.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource.Create(bildbreite, bildhoehe * 2,
                96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, ArrayAnsammlung[DurchLaeufer], stride)));
                Enkodierung.Save(dateiStrom);
                dateiStrom = null;
                Enkodierung = null;
                Nummerierungszaehler++;
            }
        }
        if (l > 0)
        {
            ArrayAnsammlung.RemoveRange(0, l);
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(60);
}
```

- DurchLaeufer is just an index.
- ArrayAnsammlung is an array that contains image data in each field. So the *for* part iterates through byte array contents.
- It all happens in a thread that runs while in another thread images are being written to ArrayAnsammlung. The buffer is necessary as more images are being delivered than processed(converted to jpeg).
- aufnahme is a bool that is true when image data is being written to ArrayAnsammlung.
- Nummerierung is a counter that helps separating the images

It works but according to a profiler it has a high load around

```
while (aufnahme || ArrayAnsammlung.Count - 1 > 0)
```

and it makes the app behave with delay.

How could I optimize this or especially use Parallel.For with this without messing up the order. So while being executed in parallel the order must be the same as in the for loop.

PS: I added

```
Thread.Sleep(60);
```

Does that help in reducing the work load?

Comment: Damn... C# with german words in between looks impossible to read for me... I just feel strange right now :S

Comment: What do you not understand, so I can translate?

Comment: Hahah don't worry it's just confusing my mind :D

Comment: If order is required, then can it really ever be done in parallel? Just for readability, it may be simpler to show `ArrayAnsammlung.Count > 1` rather than what you have.  In order to do an image filter in parallel, you would have to allow it to work on segments of the image (subimages, in essence), which would allow different pieces to be worked on in parallel, while still maintaining order for the subimage.  The problem comes at the edges of subimages, where I suspect any image filter might lose information when it comes time to blend with neighboring pixels that are unknown to the subimage.

Answer (score 3):

> it has a high load around `while (aufnahme || ArrayAnsammlung.Count - 1 > 0)`

That means it is looping a lot while the Array is empty. You can solve this with a WaitHandle, there is no reason to waste CPU on an empty collection.

But the better and easier solution would be to use `ConcurrenQueue<T>` or a `BlockingCollection` here. You can then solve this particular issue with `myQueue.Take()`.

---

Ok, the requested code sample:

```
//untested

// the new definition
private BlockingCollection<byte[]> ArrayAnsammlung = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();


while (aufnahme)
{
   byte[] data = ArrayAnsammlung.Take();

   if (data != null)
   {
     int localNum = Interlocked.Increment(ref Nummerierung);  // initialize it 1 lower

      ... // process data
   }
}
```

This is the rough idea. You may want to check how stopping with `CompleteAdding()` turns out.

---

Side issue:

```
while (aufnahme || ArrayAnsammlung.Count - 1 > 0)
{
    if (ArrayAnsammlung != null)
    {
```

The `!= null` test is too late, you already used `.Count` in the surrounding loop.

Comment: How could WaitHandle look like in this context?

Comment: You would have to share a handle between this thread and the producer-thread. But before embarking on your own Producer/Consumer, look at the available classes. Multithreading is hard go get right.

Comment: Re: side issue: But that would require try catch wouldn't it?

Comment: You can do the `!= null` outside the loop, or leave it out altogether. The current test is useless.

Comment: "Multithreading is hard go get right." Indeed. Would you mind giving me an example for my case?

Comment: Re: side issue. So you meant that ArrayAnsammlung.count in itself already proves that ArrayAnsammlung cannot be null right?

Comment: No, I mean that if it was `null` then the `.Count` would have raised an exception. The `if(ArrayAnsammlung != null)` will always be true.

Comment: In how far do I use Nummerierung in the "process data" part? BTW, it's ConcurrentQueue<T>.

Comment: Yes,  the use of Nummerierung was not thread-safe either. Added. Although it looks like it is only used in (the 1) Consumer thread.

Comment: Okay, I got it working, the images are numbered correctly and seem to be processed in parallel. But what about Waithandle, it still rushes through the while loop when ArrayAnsammlung contains no byte[] data... What would that look like?

Comment: Yes, I was mixing things up. You need a `BlockingCollection<T>`, not a Queue. And then the `Take()` will do the waiting on an empty queue. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Good, what I have so far is this: http://pastebin.com/8c3t2aWv But it seems like nothing changed.

Comment: I tried something new: http://pastebin.com/NeQHH72n It seems to interfere - ideas?

Comment: This would have to become a separate question but don't bother. That is not how to use either the Collection or Parallel.For. And real software does not Sleep().

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388836/optimizing-a-buffering-sample-for-parallel-execution-using-blockingcollection-an

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with:

```
Thread.Sleep(0);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx): "Specify zero (0) to indicate that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute."

Comment: And `Sleep(1)` would be just a little safer, but it would always have a ~20ms resolution and that makes it a crude solution.

Comment: This will just make a context switch, why would it help?