# Optimizing a buffering sample for parallel execution using BlockingCollection and Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#

Based on [Optimizing a buffering sample for parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386638/optimizing-a-buffering-sample-for-parallel-execution) this question arose.

In short:

This code throws a lot of cannot access the elements of another thread exceptions. It creates empty filenames and skips every 3 or so numbers.

Goal is to not get the numbering (Nummerierung) mixed up while converting a byte array into an image in parallel. Please refer to the link for descriptions.

What do I need to change?

```
Action action = () =>
{
    ArrayAnsammlung.TryTake(out data);
    if (data != null)
    {
        Nummerierung = Convert.ToString(Interlocked.Increment(ref Nummerierungszaehler));
        Enkodierung = null;
        Enkodierung = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        Enkodierung.FlipHorizontal = true;
        var dateiStrom = new FileStream("E:\\Temp\\" + datum + " " + Nummerierung.PadLeft(12, '0') + ".jpg", FileMode.Create);
        Enkodierung.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource.Create(bildbreite, bildhoehe * 2,
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, data, stride)));
        Enkodierung.Save(dateiStrom);
        dateiStrom = null;
        Enkodierung = null;
    }
};

while (aufnahme)
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action);
    }
    catch (AggregateException oo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oo.ToString());
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a local string for Nummerierung and again a local variable for Enkodierung, because these 2 variables are shared amongst your threads and one thread's Nummerierung and Enkodierung might be overwritten if another of the threads start to execute.

Comment: And what would that Nummerierung-String look like?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do it like this: var Nummerierung = Convert.ToString... etc so that your thread has an instance of it only for itself. Same with Enkodierung.